# Connect to a Netscreen Remote VPN from a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, vpn, netscreen

I need to connect to the company VPN. The official way to do this is using Netscreen Remote, which as far as I can tell is Windows-only. Is it possible to get connected using Snow Leopard's built-in VPN manager?

Comment: http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Mac+OS+X/2007/07/28/Juniper-Network-Connect-SSL-VPN-and-Virtualization.html

Comment: @joe: Maybe a VirtualBox with Windows7 is workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use VPN Tracker

Here the [document](http://www.equinux.com/cms_components/media/vpnt/VPNT_Interop_Howtos/59/NetScreen-3-EN.pdf) which explain about how to configure and access net-screen on mac

Comment: 118 Euro for Personal, 236 for Professional Edition. Expensive :-(

Comment: Can't you ask your boss to either get you a Windows system, or help paying that software then?

Answer (score 0):

I would say *of course* you can use the built-in client ! It should work like any other client.

For me it works perfectly, even if my University tells me to use its own client.

I think the built-in client is a complete client.